# How to play next song onClick button?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

This is my MainActivity class;

```
private ArrayList<QuerySongs> songList = new ArrayList<>();
private boolean isShuffle = false;
private boolean isRepeat = false;
public static MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

RecyclerView recyclerView;
SongAdapter songAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    if (recyclerView != null) {
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    }
    songAdapter = new SongAdapter(this, songList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(songAdapter);
    songAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(recyclerView.getContext(), linearLayoutManager.getOrientation());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);

    final TextView currSongTitle, currSongArtist;
    currSongTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.currSongTitle);
    currSongArtist = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.currSongArtist);


    final RelativeLayout relativeLayoutCurr;
    relativeLayoutCurr = findViewById(R.id.relativeLayoutCurr);

    recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new OnItemClickListeners(this, new OnItemClickListeners.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
            final String songTitle = songList.get(position).getTitle();
            //final String filePath = songList.get(position).getData();
            final int songIndex = position;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You Clicked " + songList.get(position).getData(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            try {
                mediaPlayer.reset();
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(songList.get(songIndex).getData());
                mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
                mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        mp.start();
                    }
                });

                currSongTitle.setText(songList.get(position).getTitle());
                currSongArtist.setText(songList.get(position).getArtist());
            }catch (Exception e){

                e.printStackTrace();

            }
           relativeLayoutCurr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {
                   Intent currSong = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SongActivity.class);
                   currSong.putExtra("songIndex", songIndex);
                   currSong.putExtra("songTitle", songTitle);
                   //currSong.putExtra("filePath", filePath);
                   startActivity(currSong);
               }
           });
        }
    }));


    //Methode call controle voor toestemming lezen Storage
    checkUserPermission();

    //Methode call songs inlezen
    getSongs();

    //Sort songs
    Collections.sort(songList, new Comparator<QuerySongs>() {
        public int compare(QuerySongs a, QuerySongs b) {
            return a.getTitle().compareTo(b.getTitle());
        }
    });

}

//Songs inlezen
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
public void getSongs() {

        Uri songUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + "!=0";
        Cursor myCursor = getContentResolver().query(songUri, null, selection, null, null);


        if (myCursor != null && myCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int data_Column = myCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);
            int id_Column = myCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
            int title_Column = myCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
            int artist_Column = myCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
            int album_Column = myCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM);

            do {

                String songData = myCursor.getString(data_Column);
                Long songId = myCursor.getLong(id_Column);
                String songName = myCursor.getString(title_Column);
                String songArtist = myCursor.getString(artist_Column);
                String songAlbum = myCursor.getString(album_Column);

                QuerySongs querySongs = new QuerySongs(songData, songId, songName, songArtist, songAlbum);
                songList.add(querySongs);

            } while (myCursor.moveToNext());
            myCursor.close();
            songAdapter = new SongAdapter(this, songList);
        }
}

// Toestemming Storage lezen
private void checkUserPermission() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
            getSongs();
        }
    } else {
        checkUserPermission();
    }
}

@NonNull
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestcode, @NonNull String[]
        permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestcode){
        case 1:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                getSongs();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                checkUserPermission();
                break;
            }
        default:
    }
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestcode, permissions,
            grantResults);

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mediaPlayer.stop();
    mediaPlayer.release();
}
}
```

And this is my next activity class to display the song;

```
private ArrayList<QuerySongs> songList = new ArrayList<>();
int songIndex = 0;
Button btnPlayPause, btnNext;
Bundle b;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_song);

    btnPlayPause = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPlayPause);
    btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);


    Intent currSong = getIntent();
    b = currSong.getExtras();

    btnPlayPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                        mediaPlayer.pause();
                        btnPlayPause.setText("Play");
                    } else {
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                        btnPlayPause.setText("Stop");
                    }
                    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                            btnPlayPause.setText("Play");
                        }
                    });
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });

    btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int songIndex = (int) b.get("songIndex");
            //if(songIndex < songList.size() - 1) {
                songIndex = songIndex + 1;
                try {
                    mediaPlayer.reset();
                    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(songList.get(songIndex).getData());
                    mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
                    mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                            mp.start();
                        }
                    });

                } catch (Exception e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You Clicked " + songIndex, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        //}
    });

    /*if (b != null) {
        String songTitle = (String) b.get("songTitle");
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(songTitle);
    }*/

    }
```

So how can i play the next song in my songslist when i click on btnNext and display the current playing song in the actionbar?

When i click button next, the mediaplayer stops playing and a toast shows the current song position + 1, but it's not playing the next song?

Thanks,

-Vince

SongActivity

EDIT;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_song);

    btnPlayPause = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPlayPause);
    btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

    Intent currSong = getIntent();
    b = currSong.getExtras();

    btnPlayPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                        mediaPlayer.pause();
                        btnPlayPause.setText("Play");
                    } else {
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                        btnPlayPause.setText("Stop");
                    }
                    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                            btnPlayPause.setText("Play");
                        }
                    });
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });

    btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(songIndex + 1).itemView.performClick();
            try {
                mediaPlayer.reset();
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(songList.get(songIndex).getData());
                mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
                mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        mp.start();
                    }
                });

            }catch (Exception e){

                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }

    });

    if (b != null) {
        String songTitle = (String) b.get("songTitle");
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(songTitle);
    }

}

}
```

So i made a global variable in my MainActivity and linked it to the position of my recyclerview and in my other activity i imported it.

Added this statement in my btnNext click listener;                 recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(songIndex + 1).itemView.performClick();

But now when i click next, the app crashes.

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(int)'
>   on a null object reference
>                                                                                    at
>   com.vince_mp3player.mp3player.SongActivity$2.onClick(SongActivity.java:64)

p.s im new to java so im pretty sure i'm making a dumb mistake

Thanks in advance,
-Vince

LOGCAT;

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                  Process: com.vince_mp3player.mp3player, PID: 29548
>                                                                                  Theme: themes:{}
>                                                                                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(int)'
>   on a null object reference
>                                                                                      at
>   com.vince_mp3player.mp3player.SongActivity$2.onClick(SongActivity.java:65)
>                                                                                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204)
>                                                                                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21159)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5475)
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                      at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Answer (score 2):

What i suggest is make a global variable which will keeps the hold to the current  position and programmatically click the next item in the RecyclerView and to do that use

```
recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(currentPosition + 1).itemView.performClick();
```

put the above statement in the listener of the next button and it'll automatically call the RecyclerView's OnItemTouchListener and will play the next song.

Comment: I added your statement inside my btnNext listener and made a global variable songIndex and linked that to the position of my recyclerview in MainActivity (songIndex = position) But now the app crashes when i press the next button.  (Look at edited post)

Comment: first thing you've declared the index variable like this `final int songIndex = position;` inside the OnTouchListener. Of global what I meant was define a variable before onCreate and it's value will be updated every time an recycler view item will be clicked. And button OnClickListener can read that value and act according to it. And if the problem still remains please also add the logcat.

Comment: Yeah, i created a global variable above onCreate (public static int songIndex;) , then in my recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener i linked it to position ( songIndex = position; ) and then i added the statement in my other activity in btnNext onClick listener.  
(Logcat in post)

Comment: http://textuploader.com/dqcba  , this is the code from the btnNext onClickListener, but i have an error with the statement you gave. I'm missing something but i don't know what.  Songs are displayed in MainActivity and in onclick recyclerview item i linked it with the global variable songIndex and accessed it in other activity with import. The error i get is java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(int)' on a null object reference

Comment: your RecyclerView and OnClickListener both are in different file? or in different class in single file? If both are in different files the it'll definitely show a NPE.